# How to click song list (Now Playing activity) to playing without (Music Preview) startActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-developer-api

How to click and send (**Intent** + **putExtras** + **startActivity**) in main activity (music preview activity) and playing song without showing it.
Song list stays, but clicking list song --> refresh music preview activity.
I want stay this activity (song list) but music priview activity get intent and refreshing and playing new song.

[http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1MpvIjTXByBNfFasIZ0UFI2SbkS11.jpg http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1MpvIjTXByBNfFasIZ0UFI2SbkS11.jpg](http://www.pixentral.com/pics/1MpvIjTXByBNfFasIZ0UFI2SbkS11.jpg)

song list :

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MusicPreview.class);
            intent.putExtra("pos", position).putExtra("names", SongsName).putExtra("songlist", SongsUri);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `BroadcastReceiver` for this.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Get all your music data from the intent
            String position = intent.getStringExtra("pos");
            ...
        }
 };
```

Register this `BroadcastReciever` with an `Intent` in your NowPlayingActivity's `onCreate()` like this,

```
registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("songchange"));
```

And don't forget to unregister the receiver `onDestroy()`.

```
unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
```

And then in your PlaylistActivity on List item click do this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("songchange");
intent.putExtra("pos", position);
...//pass all the needed data
sendBroadcast(intent);
```